# To import bulk data in google fusion table

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I want to import bulk data into fusion table . What is the best data format should I use to import data i.e JSON ,CSV .

If I want to import data in JSON format how can I do it since on google help only way was to upload CSV files .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import JSON data at this time (Jan. 2013). JSO data is schema-less and can be arbitrarily nested, and the fusion-table installer does not support this at this time. Maybe kml is possible.

This is a robust way to import: Use the open-source [infusion.jar](http://code.google.com/p/infusion/) file to bulk-load fusion tables with CSV data. Install Java if you don't have it. (By the way, but don't install the "helpful" tools the Java installer will ask you for, such as the ask.com toolbar, or the McAffee Security Scanner) Download the infusion.jar, and on a command line prompt, or terminal, change to the directory where you downloaded the file, and type

```
 java -jar infusion.jar
```

This will give you another very simple shell prompt.

```
    Shell Commands
  auth         Authenticate client
  exit         Quit FT demo
  help         Show this help screen
  trace        Show stack trace for last error
  import file <filename> [into <tableId>] [delimiter <delimiter>]
               [offset <offset>]
               Import a bibtex or CSV file.

Fusion Table query examples
  select * from 197026
               Display contents of table 197026
  show tables  List available tables*

*) Requies authentication

Reading access token failed

Command? auth
```

To make sense of this command, you need to be minimally familiar with the OAuth2 login-mechanisms that google uses to give write access to your google account. I don't have the time to explain this here.
Just write **auth**

```
Command? auth
```

This will open a web page in your default browser. Click on the blue "Grant access" button. 
On the next web page that will open (will contain only few lines of text), copy the bold "security token" (it's basically a password that's valid for one hour), e.g "IicETkqdmwvHFhl5sFK0z7" to the prompt

```
Verification code: IicETkqdmwvHFhl5sFK0z7
```

Then you can issue a command such as

```
import file myfile.csv delimiter ,
```

and you are done. Postprocessing must be done afterwards, use the Fusion Tables Web Site.

---

Answer (score 1):

If you have geospacial data, I've had a lot of success exporting a kml from SHP and GeoJSON with QGIS and uploading that.  If your comfortable with the command line the python CSV and JSON libraries are both very good and easy to use to convert JSON -> python dictionary -> CSV. Though that isn't going to work if you have geospatial data.